# Related_Entries how-to?

Tags: relationships, related-entries

Perhaps I've misunderstood what Related_Entries is aimed at accomplishing, but I've tried a number of variations and can't seem to get some very simple template code to parse correctly.

**Channel Setup**

I've got a Matches channel and a Teams channel. The Matches channel has two fields in it labeled as "Team 1" and "Team 2". They're both set as a Relationship to the Teams channel. I've created some test Matches and assigned Teams to them and everything appears fine there. However, I'm attempting to create a sample template using all of this information. See below:

**Template code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Matches</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<h1>List of current matches.</h1>

{exp:channel:entries channel="Matches" limit="10"}
<h2>{title}</h2>

{related_entries id="Teams" entry_id="{team_1}"}
  {team_name}
{/related_entries}

vs

{related_entries id="Teams" entry_id="{team_2}"}
  {team_name}
{/related_entries}


{/exp:channel:entries}
</body>
</html>
```

{team_1} appears to just be returning an id of some sort... I presume it is the rel_id.

**exp_relationships/clearing cache/table behavior**

To further muddy the waters, while troubleshooting, it was recommended I clear the Relationship cache within EE through the Admin interface. This action cleared out all data within the rel_data column in this table but I've yet to find an *ideal* way to repopulate this data. The only way I've found is to go into Content > Edit > Matches, edit one of the matches and CHANGE the team participating in the Match and then change it back. Simply hitting "Update" doesn't appear to re-populate the table.

**EDIT: SOLUTION**

I made a mistake and read the documentation on the related_entries tag incorrectly. The accepted answer below is based on the comment he made pointing out that I need to use the field id instead of the Channel name.

The changed line(s) should look something like

```
{related_entries id="team_1"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing `entry_id=""` the only parameter to the related_entries tag is the id parameter, which is the shortname of the relationship field.  This means the name of the field where the dropdown allowing you to select a relationship lives.  As an example, I have a channel called `programs` in which the channel field naming convention is three letter channel code underscore 2 letter language code underscore name.  Here is my code for one of those related_entries tags:

```
{related_entries id="pro_related_program"}
    <p>This session is part of a larger series.  For more information see <a href="{title_permalink="programs/catalogue"}" title="TDLC: {title}">{title}</a></p>
{/related_entries}
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to return anything either. That's was the first thing I had tried based on the documentation. I appreciate the input though.

The way it was described to me was that if I provided only that information, EE would try to return ALL the members of that channel and I only want a specific one.

Comment: To elaborate a bit, the {title} prints fine however the code between {related_entries} returns nothing. If I use the code as I presented up above, it at least returns an Integer which appears to relate to the rel_id.

Comment: id="" should not contain a channel, it should contain the name of the field where you've defined the relationship.

Comment: That makes sense! Not sure why I never thought to just try that. I misinterpreted the documentation which in their example uses the same name for the Channel as well as the relationship field.

Thank you.

Comment: Might be worth adding a clarifying note at the end of the documentation too if using the same name caused confusion for you it is likely to confuse others too.  Very glad I could help.